# Eclipse Plugin Development: How to show my custom tooltip at the cursor position?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I already know how to retrieve my current cursor location and I even have the information I want to show; now I would need to know how I can show a custom tooltip in a certain position in the current Editor window (the standard one in Eclipse), just like you can see here: [image: The kind of tooltip I want to show]

It would be awesome if it could be shown just when the mouse hovers over, but if that's too difficult, it's enough if it's triggered by a menu button / shortkey and takes the current cursor position.

Comment: Show it in what? An existing editor? An editor you are writing? Something else? A 3.x compatability mode plug-in or a plug-in for e4? What should trigger the tooltip?

Comment: For an existing editor you have to use the extension points provided by the editor. You can't really do this for all editors.

Comment: And can I do this only for the Eclipse standard editor? How can I access the extension points of an editor?

Comment: There is no 'standard editor' - there is dozens of editors for different things. Most are based on the core text editor code but you can't contribute to the core code. You access the extension points by looking them up in the Eclipse help, for  example for the Java editor it might be the [org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaEditorTextHovers](https://help.eclipse.org/2020-03/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_jdt_ui_javaEditorTextHovers.html) extension point.

Comment: That is impossible to say, it depends what you want it to do. There is a whole section on [Editors](https://help.eclipse.org/2020-03/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Feditors.htm&cp%3D2_0_13) in the help, there is also the newer [Generic Editor](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7/M3/#generic-editor) or even [Eclipse xText](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) if you want to handle a specific programming language.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212846/discussion-between-benjamin-zach-and-greg-449).

Comment: I don't do chat. This question is too broad